# Preview permalink page when customizing tumblr theme

Tags: themes, tumblr, permalinks, preview

When developing a Tumblr theme using the built-in tools, is there a way to preview what a permalink page will look like instead of the index page?

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it isn't possible to preview a permalink page via the Tumblr customise / editor preview.

The only option you get is to choice between the dummy posts or your own posts.